# How to disable public IP for an existing EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a group of EC2 instances associated with different security groups, let's say a `private-security-group` and a `public-security-group`. I have set up a VPN running on an EC2 instance with it's own security-group. I have configured my instances in such a way that:

- The instances associated with the `private-security-group` are accessible through the VPN tunnel
- The instances associated with the `private-security-group` are accessible by other instances associated with the `public-security-group`

This means that no inbound traffic can reach out to the instances from the internet. For that reason, I would like to remove the public IP address that is automatically allocated to those instance as a next layer of security so that I would have a series of instances running on a private network (but I may need access to the internet occasionally).

The main problem here is that I cannot recreate those instances as it will be very time consuming. How can I remove the automatically assigned public IP that is attached to a running instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete it once it is associated with the instance. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#public-ip-addresses):

> You **cannot** manually associate or **disassociate** a public IP (IPv4) address from your instance.

You have to re-recreate your instances without public ip.

Comment: I had already found this. So is there really no other way?!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder I think documentation is clear, you have no control over it. It is managed by AWS, not you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In your opinion, do you think removing the public IP in this case (regardless of being possible or not) is a good security practice?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Usually blocking internet access from SG would be enough and/or network ACL.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder No problem. But if you were to re-create your instances you can use Elastic IP, which you can attach and detatch manually from the instance.

Comment: and just for faster re-creation, you can "clone" the EC2 instance and run a new one from it (it is going to create a snapshot and you can run the instance from the snapshot)

Comment: Now that AWS started charging for public IPv4 addresses, they could facilitate disassociating them!